# javadoc for all - private, public and protected members

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I want to have a javadoc where all - private , public, protected members are shown. In eclipse I am having option to make javadoc for either of the three, not for all the three types of members. How can I accomplish this?? [no option to add all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw7ZZ.png)

Comment: @carlos answer is correct. The UI is confusing because it implies that you are only generating javadoc for `private`. But actually, selecting `private` is the lower bound. It will generate all members.

Answer (score 1):

The option that you can set on the Javadoc export wizard is just the lower *bound* of which classes and members will be documented. Upper *bound* is always "public".

Options:

- Public: only public classes and members,
- Protected: protected and public classes and members,
- Package: package, protected and public classes and members,
- Private: all classes and members

Answer (score 0):

Using the terminal, simply use the `javadoc` command with the `-private` argument. For example `javadoc *.java -private` to generate javadoc for all .java files in the current directory.
[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqQ98.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**Make usage of the '-private'**

Let's give you an example:

The following command line will process all the packages under com **and** LOR (lord of the rings) located into /home/rudy/IdeaProjects/demo/src/main/java **and** /home/rudy/IdeaProjects/demo/src/test/java/

Please note:

- it is Linux and the paths and packages are separated by ':'.
- that I made usage of '-private' and wanted all the classes and members to be documented.

---

```
rudy@rudy-ThinkPad-T590:~$ javadoc -d /home/rudy/IdeaProjects/demo_doc
-sourcepath /home/rudy/IdeaProjects/demo/src/main/java/
:/home/rudy/IdeaProjects/demo/src/test/java/
-subpackages com:LOR 
-private

rudy@rudy-ThinkPad-T590:~/IdeaProjects/demo/src/main/java$ ls -R 
.: com LOR
./com: example
./com/example: demo
./com/example/demo: DemowApplication.java
./LOR: Race.java TolkienCharacter.java

rudy@rudy-ThinkPad-T590:~/IdeaProjects/demo/src/test/java$ ls -R 
.: com
./com: example
./com/example: demo
./com/example/demo: AssertJTest.java DemowApplicationTests.java
```